# pandas: how to assign a single column conditionally on multiple other columns?

Tags: pandas

I'm confused about conditional assignment in Pandas.

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
   { 'stripe_subscription_id': 1, 'status': 'past_due' },
   { 'stripe_subscription_id': 2, 'status': 'active' },
   { 'stripe_subscription_id': None, 'status': 'active' },
   { 'stripe_subscription_id': None, 'status': 'active' },
])
```

I'm trying to add a new column, conditionally based on the others:

```
def get_cancellation_type(row):
    if row.stripe_subscription_id:
        if row.status == 'past_due':
            return 'failed_to_pay'
        elif row.status == 'active':
            return 'cancelled_by_us'
    else:
        return 'cancelled_by_user'
df['cancellation_type'] = df.apply(get_cancellation_type, axis=1)
```

This is fairly readable, but is it the standard way to do things?

I've been looking at `pd.assign`, and am not sure if I should be using that instead.

Comment: Do you mind to add the expected output?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: no idea. The question seems well written to me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you can change or add the conditions however you want.

```
df.loc[(df['stripe_subscription_id'] != np.nan) & (df['status'] == 'past_due'), 'cancellation_type'] = 'failed_to_pay'
df.loc[(df['stripe_subscription_id'] != np.nan) & (df['status'] == 'active'), 'cancellation_type'] = 'cancelled_by_us'
df.loc[(df['stripe_subscription_id'] == np.nan), 'cancellation_type'] = 'cancelled_by_user'
```

Answer (score 0):

You migth consider to use `np.select`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
condList = [df["status"]=="past_due",
            df["status"]=="active",
            ~df["status"].isin(["past_due",
                                "active"])]


choiceList = ["failed_to_pay", "cancelled_by_us", "cancelled_by_user"]

df['cancellation_type'] = np.select(condList, choiceList)
```